# Process csv file stored in blob storage using Python Azure functions

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I have a csv file with 'n' number of records stored in blob storage. I want to read the new records being added to the csv file, process it and stored it back to another container in the blob storage. I want to achieve this flow using Python Azure Functions. I am unable to write the code for inbound and outbound in the Python Azure Functions.

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code that worked for me. I'm using HTTP Trigger to achieve your requirement.

#### function.json

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "anonymous",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "direction":"in",
      "name": "inputblob",
      "path": "input/input.csv",
      "connection": "storageacc_STORAGE"
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "direction":"out",
      "name": "outputblob",
      "path": "output/output.csv",
      "connection": "storageacc_STORAGE"
    }
  ]
}
```

#### **init**.py

```
import csv
import logging

import azure.functions as func


def main(req: func.HttpRequest, inputblob: func.InputStream,outputblob: func.Out[bytes]) -> func.InputStream:
    
    # Reading from the input binding
    input_file = inputblob.read()
    
    # Processing the csv file

    # Writing to output binding
    outputblob.set(input_file)
```

#### local.settings.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "storageacc_STORAGE": "<Your_Connection_String>"
  }
}
```

**RESULTS:**

[image]

[image]

Comment: what is the type of `input_file` when you're storing it?